# How to increase io performances of this piece of code

Tags: java, performance, io, random-access

How can I make this piece of code extremely quick?
It reads a raw image using RandomAccessFile (in) and write it in a file using DataOutputStream (out)

```
final int WORD_SIZE = 4;
byte[] singleValue = new byte[WORD_SIZE];
long position;

    for (int i=1; i<=100000; i++)
    {
             out.writeBytes(i + " ");

             for(int j=1; j<=17; j++)
             {
                  in.seek(position);
                  in.read(singleValue);                     
                  String str = Integer.toString(ByteBuffer.wrap(singleValue).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt());
                  out.writeBytes(str + " ");
                  position+=WORD_SIZE;      
             }
             out.writeBytes("\n");
    }
```

The inner `for` creates a new line in the file every 17 elements

Thanks

Comment: First of all: Remove the System.out :-)

Comment: @achingfingers hahahahah, thanks :)

Comment: Use a `BufferedOutputStream` in addition to `DataOutputStream` to avoid writing each primitive element.

Comment: Also are you sure you need a `RandomAccessFile`?

Comment: Am I right you read all bytes sequentialy ? If so, why using a RandomAccessFile and not just an FileInputStream with a BufferedInputStream?

Comment: @Eypros read the comment I wrote below for Conffusion's answer

Comment: Allocating a `ByteBuffer` for every 4 bytes, can't be a good idea. Reading a memory mapped file (via `ByteBuffer`) should be faster. Or use `DataOutputStream` around a `BufferedOutputStream` as suggested and `Integer.reverseBytes` to change the byte order.

Comment: @maaartinus How would you change this line of code using `Integer.reverseBytes`: `String str = Integer.toString(ByteBuffer.wrap(singleValue).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the reason you are asking is because this code is running really slowly.  If that is the case, then one reason is that each `seek` and `read` call is doing a system call.  A `RandomAccessFile` has no buffering.  (I'm guessing that `singleValue` is a `byte[]` of length 1.)

So the way to make this go faster is to step back and think about what it is actually doing.  If I understand it correctly, it is reading each 4th byte in the file, converting them to decimal numbers and outputting them as text, 17 to a line.  You could easily do that using a `BufferedInputStream` like this:

```
    int b = bis.read();  // read a byte
    bis.skip(3);         // skip 3 bytes.
```

(with a bit of error checking ....).  If you use a `BufferedInputStream` like this, most of the `read` and `skip` calls will operate on data that has already been buffered, and the number of syscalls will reduce to 1 for every N bytes, where N is the buffer size.

**UPDATE** - my guess was wrong.  You are actually reading alternate words, so ...

```
    bis.read(singleValue);
    bis.skip(4);
```

---

> Every 100000 offsets I have to jump 200000 and then do it again till the end of the file.

Use `bis.skip(800000)` to do that.  It should do a big skip by moving the file position without actually reading any data.  One syscall at most.  (For a `FileInputStream`, at least.)

---

You can also speed up the output side by a roughly equivalent amount by wrapping the `DataOutputStream` around a `BufferedOutputStream`.

But `System.out` is already buffered.

Comment: My singleValue is a byte[4]. I read 4 byte convert them in little endian and then save the result

Comment: Done, It is a bit faster. To increase performance I did also `out.writeBytes(Integer.toString(ByteBuffer.wrap(singleValue).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt()) + " ");`

Comment: Stephen C Thanks a lot

Comment: I expect that using `ByteBuffer` to do the conversion makes little difference to the overall performance.

Comment: Did you use a BufferedOutputStream too?   Get rid of System.out stuff?  If not try both of those.  I predict a big speedup.